# How to determine the username and its group via UID?

Tags: linux, bash

How to determine the username and its group via UID

Comment: What kind of user? Local? LDAP? Databse? Can you give us some context? Is this just for a simple, locally defined user with an entry in `/etc/passwd`? Is this only about Linux or does it need to be portable? Please [edit] and clarify.

Answer (score 4):

I think `id` can work well with more authentication backend (tested on an LDAP domain).

```
# Get the username for your UID
id -un

# Get the username for someone else UID
id -un UID
```

The same as above but for the group :

```
id -gn

id -gn UID
```

Of course if i understand well your question (without  real/effective userid and groupid implications)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `id` command for that:

```
id <UID>
```

Comment: Will that work for an [LDAP user](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Directory_Access_Protocol)?

Comment: This will output a lot of info. Numerical uid and name, numerical gid and  name and all supplementary groups ids and names.

Comment: The question wasn't asked any more specific.